# What does 'overpowered by the fumes' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

In the page of '[overpower](https://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/overpower#:%7E:text=they%20were%20overpowered%20by%20the%20fumes)' in *encyclopedia.com*, there's such a sentence as follows.

> They were overpowered by the fumes.

The explanation of 'overpower' in that sentence given by *encyclopedia.com* is

> be too intense for; overwhelm.

However, I don't quite get what that sentence exactly means. I wonder if the people in that sentence passed out due to the fumes or their actions were restricted by the fumes, or something else.

Comment: Without context, I could imagine people passing out, being unable to enter a space because of the smell, being unable to enter a space because the fumes caused pain or injury, etc.

Comment: The definition appears good. Do you understand what "intense" and "overwhelm" mean? If not, have you looked up those words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example would need context to know exactly what it meant, but *overcome*, *overwhelm*, *overpower* etc all carry roughly the same meaning which is that something had a particular potency or power that beat something or someone else.

To give you an idea of the range of meanings in different contexts - an 'overpowering smell' could just be an unpleasant assault on the senses that prevents you from smelling anything else, but to say a person was 'overcome by fumes' could mean that they asphyxiated.